# SQL Server CLR procedures and SQLCLR_QUANTUM_PUNISHMENT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-clr, wait-types

I have a CLR stored procedure running on SQL Server 2014.  This stored procedure gathers some data (generally numbering in the tens-of-thousands of rows range), runs some computations on the data, generating an output dataset, and writes that output dataset to a couple of destination tables.  For small runs, this takes a few seconds.  For our larger runs, it's currently taking about 25 minutes.  During that 25 minutes, we have observed a significant number of SQLCLR_QUANTUM_PUNISHMENT waits.  So I'm trying to educate myself on what we can do to reduce the occurrence of these waits.  I've found plenty of resources that tell me, "Occurs when a CLR task is throttled because it has exceeded its execution quantum. This throttling is done in order to reduce the effect of this resource-intensive task on other tasks."  And I've read that SQL Server's execution quantum is 4ms.  So am I to assume that any time a CLR stored procedure or function takes more that 4ms of CPU time, this wait type will occur?

Also, I found a [reference indicating that some CLR procedures should be yielding](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlclr/2006/04/10/who-says-tough-guys-never-yield/).  Now, our CLR procedure is single-threaded.  I can certainly add some sleep calls at key places and see what kind of affect that has.  But I would like to have a better understanding of what's going on.  So if anyone has some good knowledge to share or has a link to a good document/article, I would appreciate it.  Finding information about this wait type beyond that BOL quote has been a bit difficult.

Comment: I can recommend you watch [Data, Faster: Microsoft SQL Server Performance Techniques with SQLCLR](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2013/DBI-B404) by Adam Machanic.

Comment: That was an *excellent* video!  thank you very much for sharing it.  It not only answered this question, but gave me some excellent pointers for another issue I was thinking about... how to successfully manipulate the CLR procedure to make user of multiple threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not a lot of information out there on this topic. I can say that yes, you certainly should add the `Thread.Sleep(0);` to various places in your code. Doing so gives SQL Server an opportunity to control the thread. This is not necessary in places that are doing data access (i.e. `SqlClient` stuff) as SQL Server already has the ability to manage that.

Also, @Remus Rusanu, in another question (perhaps on Stack Overflow) had recommended using [Thread.BeginThreadAffinity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.beginthreadaffinity.aspx) / [Thread.EndThreadAffinity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.endthreadaffinity.aspx) to manage long-running processes, but using those requires that the Assembly be set to `UNSAFE`.

Comment: I second that advice: Add `Thread.BeginThreadAffinity / Thread.EndThreadAffinity` to you CLR code entry/exit points.

Comment: @RemusRusanu To all or just long-running? Does the fact that it requires `UNSAFE` reduce some of the benefit that it provides? And lastly, why exactly does it help? The MSDN documentation makes it sound like it mostly does not apply.

Comment: The problem is that CLR code is supposed to be participating in the SQL OS cooperative multitasking as a well behaved threadizen. If the code is stealing the thread and is running away without yielding, it prevents other tasks from making progress as the scheduler is never given a chance to switch context. For this, when finally it yields, is punished (as a warning to the developer...). UNSAFE has nothing to do with it, afaik.

Comment: BTA/ETA is making the thread preemptive. When this happens, the scheduler is given away to the next non-preemptive thread and the preemptive thread continues. when this occurs, 2 threads are 'runnable' from underlying OS pov (I almost said NT...) and there may be CPU contention inside SQL process, but that is a separate topic. The CLR code will run until ETA and then it will try to join back the cooperative mode. There is a cost with switching BTA/ETA, so it should be done only for lengthy CLR code.